# How to create a boolean column that compares the value of the next n rows with the actual value of a row

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe df, I would like to generate a new column for each row based on the values in the next n rows (for example next 3). And in case, if the value is greater than x (for example 30) then returns 1, else 0.

For example, given the following:

INPUT

```
A  B  C
14 3 32
28 3 78
15 4 68
42 3 42
24 4 87
13 3 65
```

Calculation for D: if any of the next n rows (in this case 3) have a value that is >= than the actual row (n)+30  then return 1, else 0

OUTPUT

```
A  B  C  D
14 3 32  1     # 32+30 = 62 so [78>=62, 68>=62]
28 3 78  0     # 78+30 = 108 
15 4 68  0     # 68+30 = 98
42 3 42  1     # 42+30 = 72 so [87>=72]  
24 4 87  0     # 87+30 = 117
13 3 65  0     # 65+30 = 95
```

How should I do it in pandas?

Comment: For `C=42`, `65<72`, then why `D=1` ?

Comment: my bad, already edited the INPUT, I changed the values after, so it would be easier to see the example, sorry about that.

Comment: Is this for any column, or just C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['D'] = np.where((df.C+30<=df.C.shift(-1)) | ((df.C+30<=df.C.shift(-2))),1,0)
```

Output:

```
     A  B   C   D
0   14  3   32  1
1   28  3   78  0
2   15  4   68  0
3   42  3   42  1
4   24  4   87  0
5   13  3   65  0
```

Comment: Just a kindly suggestion , when you provide the solution , make it more flexible,(For example when he need check forward 6 ,it is hard for us making 6 `shift`.) PS: still voted for you.

Comment: @Wen agreed. Your solution has the flexibility that my solution does not. Voted +1 to yours.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC `rolling`

```
df.C.iloc[::-1].rolling(3,min_periods=1).max().iloc[::-1].gt(df.C+30).astype(int)
Out[509]: 
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
Name: C, dtype: int32
```